# Draw stroke around UIComponent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

My project uses a third party libraries (as3svgrendererlib) for drawing SVG. It draws shapes as expected, correctly. After that my application should apply its own effects (like fill, stroke, filters) which I implemented with the help of mask. Fills and filters work for me, but stroke - doesn't.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth: Number, unscaledHeight: Number): void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    mask = getComponentMask();

    if (_fillOptions)
    {
        var g: Graphics = graphics;
        var f: IFill = _fillOptions.fill;
        var tb: Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        var to: Point = new Point(0, 0);
        var s: IStroke = _strokeOptions.stroke;

        s.apply(g, tb, to);
        f.begin(g, tb, to);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        f.end(g);
    }
}
```

So what is the possible ways to draw stroke around existing UIComponent?

Thank you.

-Viktor Burdeinyi

Comment: What is in your getComponentMask() method ? Did you trace your width and height to ensure they're correct ?

Comment: getComponentMask() returns the SVGDocument or TextField instances, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate a stroke you may use a `GlowFilter` with its strength and alpha to the max.

Comment: The code Viktor wrote should work, so I guess it would be better to try to understand why it doesn't than to propose alternative solutions.

Comment: The code works, but the stroke were drawn only in places where mask crosses with bounds of Rectangle(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight).

Comment: So I guess the problem is your mask isn't properly placed.

Comment: LoremIpsum, could you please explain in more details what did you mean under? Thank you.

Comment: When sometimes I don't get the drawings I expect, I begin by disabling any mask to see if the drawings are made. This way, I can accurately know if the mask or the drawings are the root of the problem.